# Actions not available in wizard (Odoo)

Tags: view, odoo, action, wizard

I am trying to access the list view of the product.template model in a [wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXPP3.png) by clicking a button located in a random form view. The problem I am facing is that I don't have the [actions menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVL9E.png) available in the wizard.

How can I add the action menu bar in the wizard?

The method that I am using:

```
def product_template_list_view(self):
    for record in self:
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'name': _('Products'),
            'res_model': 'product.template',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'target': 'new',
        }
```

Comment: Some features like print/action menu and even chatter aren't available in dialogs (popups). Maybe not using a dialog could be an alternative?

Comment: @CZoellner Can I extend the dialogs and give them the option to have the print and action menu?

Comment: Everything is possible, but for what how much (money/time)? :D